# Padding in combination with :before in CSS

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="a" style="height: 100px; background: red; padding-top: 40px">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="b" style="height: 100px; background: red; padding-top: 40px">
</div>
```

and my css

```
.a:before { background-color: green; height:10px;display: block; content: " "; }
.b { border-top: solid 10px green; }
```

and here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LZgYP/

I want the first div tag to look like the second.

I want to use :before to add border (instead of border-top) to the div tag because I'll be using patterns (images) later. But I want the padding *after* the border, not before. Is there a way?

I'm building a generic SCSS library to specify the top border. Users can select a solid border or a pattern - I'll have a library of patterns too. In case of pattern I guess the only option is to use :before and specify a background image with repeat-x. Therefore I want to remain consistent and use :before to specify the border and I want this border to stick to the top even if the actual tag has padding specified.

And since this is generic, I will not know what padding the tag has, so negative margins on the :before css can't be used

Comment: without knowing what you're trying to do with the images, any help will be iffy.  Just supply what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @Dave edited my question, please see the last two paragraphs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must confess that I can't understand why you don't want to go with a simple border, still here's what I'd do to mimick a border-top. I'd place a :before pseudo-element absolutely positioned to the top. Only prerequisite is to relative position the main div so the pseudo element can be placed on top.

```
.a:before { 
    background-color: green; 
    height:10px; 
    content: ""; 
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;}
```

Here's a fiddle, hope it solves the issue, http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/ZVUFv/1/

Comment: Thanks Nobita, didn't think about that. I can't use border-top because I also want to use an image pattern as the border.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. So what about something simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/ZVUFv/2/

Comment: Can I use image as a box-shadow? At the moment I'm using :before { background: url (/img.jpg) repeat-x;}

Comment: Oh right, in that case you'd better stick to the first version. Thanks for accepting, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

**Answer UPDATED:**
add padding-bottom to the `a:before` and remove padding-top from `DIV a`

```
<div class="x" style="height: 100px; background: red;">
    blah blah
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="y" style="height: 100px; background: red;">
    blah blah
</div>
```

and

```
.a:before { background-color: green; height:10px;display: block; content: " ";padding-bottom:40px }
.b:before { background-color: green; height:10px;display: block; content: " ";margin-bottom:40px }
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZgYP/11/)

Comment: Please read the last two paragraphs of my question. I can't do what you are asking me to

Comment: i edit my link. you are giving padding-top to your first div. and it it is not related to the `:before` you used in your css. when you add padding top to a DIV all off inline tags will affect

Comment: you can add your border like a background image for `DIV c`

Comment: thanks for the help. But I don't want to add additional div tags. Its a generic CSS library, users should be able to add a border by using a specifying just a CSS class on any existing element.